# Unable to Access GitLab via External Server URL Instead of Localhost

Tags: networking, docker-compose, gitlab, localhost, external-url

I am facing an issue while trying to set up integration between GitLab and Jenkins. My goal is to access GitLab using an external server URL (e.g., gitlab.automationtools.me) instead of the default localhost. However, despite my efforts to modify the GitLab configuration file and the "etc/hosts" file, I am unable to access GitLab through the external URL

I have followed various tutorials and documentation to configure GitLab with an external URL. I modified the docker-compose.yml file to set the external_url in the GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG environment variable. Additionally, I tried to manually modify the GitLab configuration file (gitlab.rb) to specify the external URL, but unfortunately, this didn't yield the desired results.
I expect to be able to access GitLab using the external server URL (http://gitlab.automationtools.me:8081/) and perform Git operations through this URL.